# Powershell - Read timestamp from file and output log with timestamp and information

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script that needs to read the last 24hours from a file that contains a specific information and error. The file that is read also has timestamps.

The current script looks like this:

```html
#Declare Variables
$FileToCheck = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\powershellshit\Read File\Log1.txt"
$DestinationFile = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\powershellshit\Output File\LogOutput1_log.txt"
$CheckTrue = "Authenticated"
$CheckFalse = "Error code"


#Declaring last 24 hours
$date0 = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("dddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")

Get-Content $FiletoCheck | Select -Last 50 | Select-String $date0 | Select-String $CheckTrue,$CheckFalse | out-file $DestinationFile

Write-Host $result
```

My problem is the following:

The script does not output anything into $Destination.

If I comment out Select-String $date0 like this <#Select-String $date0 |", the script will output the contents from $FileToCheck, but with no timestamps, because it will read the last 50 lines of code.

What I need from the script is to **read and output** the last 24hours with the $CheckTrue and $CheckFalse variables.

The contents of the $FileToCheck are like this so you can use them as test:

```html
Start script 19-02-2023 23:20:01,50 
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Authenticated.
Error code: 3
Error message from server: Permission denied
(A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip, Ski(p) all: Skip
No session.
___________________________________________________________________________________

Start script 20-02-2023 23:20:01,18 
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Authenticated.
```

I added 19th and 20th dates just for testing.

The result of the LogOutput1_log.txt file I expect is something like this:

19-02-2023 23:20:01,50 - Error code
OR
20-02-2023 23:20:01,18 - Authenticated

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: What does reading "with the $CheckTrue and $CheckFalse variables." mean? What do you want to use these variables for?

Comment: Also, date format `"dddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"` does not match the format in the file..

Answer (score 0):

First, change date format to *"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"*. Your format in script and format in file are different.